# Pyarmor ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyarmor_runtime_000000'

Tags: python, obfuscation, pyarmor

I'm trying to obfuscate my project but got error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyarmor_runtime_000000', So I tried to obfuscate a very simple folder containing only 2 files as follows

```
test
├── __init__.py
├── test2.py
└── test.py
```

the content of each file is simply a print statement. I used this command to obfuscate `pyarmor gen test`,
which result in this structure of dist folder

```
├── pyarmor_runtime_000000
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── pyarmor_runtime.so
└── test
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── test2.py
    └── test.py
```

then i run  `python PATH/dist/test/test.py` but i get error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyarmor_runtime_000000'`

I'm using pyarmor latest version, my OS is ubuntu and python version is 3.10